# nginx и несколько виртуальных dns-имен, привязанных к ip-адресу в локальной сети

Tags: nginx

```
    stream {
upstream asdserv {
  server 10.20.10.10:1521;
}
upstream qweserv {
  server 10.10.10.11:1433;
}
  server {
  listen 1433 so_keepalive=on;
  listen 1521 so_keepalive=on;
  proxy_pass asdserv;
   }
  server {
  listen 10.20.10.11:1433;
  proxy_pass qweserv;
   }
   }
```

proxy_pass с asdserv работает как нужно.
Нужно сделать несколько dns-имен, к которым будет проксирование.
Примерная схема:
[image: схема]

Что имею на данный момент:

Сам же доступ от всех серверов 10.10.10.* работает до 10.20.10.10:1521. к БД подключается и читает информацию.
К этому же конфигу нужно добавить доступ из под 10.20.10.11 до каждой БД 10.10.10.*(10-15) Попытался сделать так, как описал выше, nginx выдает ошибку duplicate "0.0.0.0:1433" address and port pair.
До БД я стучусь по dns-имени qweserv, когда в hosts файле: qweserv 10.21.10.10 и asdserv 10.21.10.10.

Comment: Подскажите, что использовать, куда копать и как это реализовать с помощью именно nginx?

Comment: Это один конфиг? Или два на разных машинах?

Comment: И при чём тут DNS?

Comment: Это один конфиг. в БД использую запросы на чтение. Обращаюсь к БД по dns-имени. Так же, забыл упомянуть, прямой доступ ко всем хостам имеет только хост с nginx. 10.20.10.10 не имеет прямого доступа к 10.10.10.10 итд.

Comment: Тогда у вас что-то IP в конфиге и на картинке не сходятся

Comment: Вот я и пытаюсь понять, что не сходится.. запутался. Я пытаюсь пока хотя бы до одного хоста в левой части подключиться и проверить работоспособность..

Comment: Исправьте вопрос

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как его исправить корректно? в том-то и дело, что я не понимаю, как в конфиг-файле правильно "маршрутизацию" прописать.

Comment: Я имею в виду исправьте несоответствие картинки и конфига. У вас в конфиге `listen 10.20.10.11`, а на картинке `10.21.10.10`.

Comment: Исправил сам вопрос в теме. ip-адрес самого nginx и не используется в конфиге. На схеме его оставил для более понятной картины. Вся суть -  чтобы все соединения обрабатывал nginx. До БД я стучусь по dns-имени qweserv, когда в hosts файле: qweserv 10.21.10.10.

Comment: Ну и какой нам толк он ненастоящего конфига? Сейчас ваш вопрос максимально непонятен

Comment: Так я настоящий конфиг и скинул, доступ к 10.20.10.10 у меня есть в этом конфиге. Так же, пытался в нем сделать доступ к одному из серверов 10.10.10.11, который в конфиге обозвал qweserv. В конфиге вроде как заставил слушать "listen 10.20.10.11:1433;" и при обращении к nginx, думаю, что nginx отправит запрос на 10.10.10.11.

Comment: У машинки с nginx есть IP адрес `10.20.10.11`?

Comment: Нет, машинка с nginx  - 10.21.10.10. И нужно чтобы весь трафик между левой и правой частями шел через эту машинку с nginx(которая посередине на картинке.

Comment: Ну так запрос на IP `10.20.10.11` на неё и не придёт в таком случае.

Comment: Вообще всё больше кажется что вам нужен не nginx,  а обычный NAT.

Comment: Ещё непонятно почему первый серверный блок слушает два порта и проксирует оба в один asdserv.

Comment: Да, нужен по сути программный NAT... но хотелось бы это через nginx сделать.

Comment: А по поводу первого серверного блока - На всякий случай оба порта добавил для прослушки, т.к. из базы msql стучусь в oracle( 1433 и 1521 порты).